# How to pixelate image paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick, paperclip, imagemagick-convert

I am new user of paperclip and I have successfully uploaded image But I want to save photo in pixelate form so that It will not more visible and not identifiable.

But I am not sure how to implement it with paperclip

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => "100x100#",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "200x200" }
end
```

[image: I want save photo in like that]

Comment: Use CarrierWave instead of Paperclip

Comment: @Rodrigo Can you guide me how to achieve this by CarrierWave. I am new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "*ImageMagick*" to pixlate image..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => "100x100#",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "200x200",
      :pixlated => ['40x40#', 'png']},
    :convert_options => {
      :pixlated => '-scale 50% -scale 1000%'}
end
```

change scale % as per your need. You will get pixlated image. I hope it will help you.

for examlple: pixlated.png

[image]

original.png

[image]

Comment: Another solution by imagemagic is:  convert -resize 8x8 -quantize sRGB +dither -scale 100% -scale 1000% -flop /original.jpg /toriginal5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You don't use paperclip for that specific functionality (Paperclip only uploads & organizes files) -- you'll need to use [ImageMagick](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor) for that

I can give you more details if this is the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Please provide me more details, I am looking for this

Comment: Another solution by imagemagic is: convert -resize 8x8 -quantize sRGB +dither -scale 100% -scale 1000% -flop /original.jpg /toriginal5.jpg